# Why do I get Problem does not follow DCP rules error?

Tags: python, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I am trying to code a convex problem with cvxpy. I am getting Problem does not follow DCP rules error. I am new to this area.

[This is the equation I am trying to code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxWCW.png)

A : positive semi definitive and nonnegative matrix A ∈ R^d×d
s: column vector  ∈ R^d
z: score  ∈ R^d

My code as below:

> pip install cvxpy

```py
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp

d = 10


A = np.random.rand(d, d)  
A = np.dot(A.transpose(),A) # This is for creating a positive semi definitive matrix.

lmbd = 0.1

z = cp.Variable(d)
s = np.random.randn(d)

objective = cp.Minimize(lmbd**2 * cp.matmul(z.T,cp.matmul(A, z)) - lmbd*cp.matmul(z.T, s))

constraint = [cp.sum(z) == 1, z >= 0]

prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraint)

print("Optimal value", prob.solve())
print("Optimal var")
```

[This is the error I get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/verx7.png)

Look forward your help, thank you!

Comment: Read the DCP rules to see why it's not DCP (basically because you multiplied two variables without guaranteeing convexity). You probably want to use [`cvxpy.quad_form`](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/functions/index.html#scalar-functions) to express the convex structure you are interested in.

Comment: Thank you so much. It solved my problem.